# To use Power banks and DC-DC step up Converter to make Electric Bicycle battery Pack

Tags: power, usb, converter

Summary of the whole project 
[image]

I have a small project in mind, just want to find out is this a possible way to make a useful power pack rather then use this normal way 
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

to make a traditional E-bike power pack

situation

1. I will use twelve QC 3.0 capable power banks to constantly supply 20V with around 0.9A, then I parallel them by joining 12 outputs into a thick copper wire.
2. Because the DC-DC step up converter can only handle 15 Ampere max input (10 Ampere if no cooling, so I choose limit to 10 amp )
3. step on converter specification: It can take in 16-60 Volt as input      ( with max Current 15 Amp ) output voltage is 18-80 Volt with max current 10 Amp
4. If need more power, I might make another step up converter group or groups, later join both (or all 3) step up converters output before BMS ( battery management system )

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

5. 500W motor will get electrical power from BMS :)

ok, now come some questions

1. How do I ground the circuit? Do I need to ground the circuit? Is it necessary??
2. If I use 2-3 step up converter groups, how should I deal with the grounding circuit problem?
3. Do I need to put diode ? Especially just outside output of each power banks . If No need Diode , then I can save more energy :)
4. Do I need to put diode outside the step up converter ? I means in between steps up converter groups and BMS
5. Any other points that might stop the project from working ?

Comment: was trying to upload more picture, failed

Comment: Please be aware that if your 20V battery buss is limited to 10 amps, your TOTAL power (including converter inefficiency) is 200 W max. So call your motor power on the order of 160 to 180 watts, or 1/3 of your expected power. Is this acceptable?

Comment: Upload them to imgur and add a link in the comments,  We will edit them in

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast that is why I am thinking to use 3 groups of converter let me try, I am still new to this site :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/YGZJD


these are the link to the photos that I suppose to upload, one is sample photo of a traditional battery

another photo is the way I am intend to add more converter group 

thanks @Passerby

Comment: Did you compare 1) how long one charge of your battery packs will last compared to a regular e-bike accu? 2) how many charge/discharge cyles at this high power level your power packs will survive (compared, again, to a regular e-bike accu)?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen i know it might not hold as much power nor it might not be as easy, but the buy a traditional power pack is quite pricy , to make one for yourself ( DIY ) , there is alot of investment .

if I use power bank, the most I just need a few multi port USB charger, I can easily charge at home and in company

how much the load can hold, i think it should be slightly inferior compare to the traditional only, but it is much cheaper ( alot of cheap power bank in Alibaba , but premium 18650 will cost 4-6 USD per piece :(

Comment: @TerryLim - Glad you posted the picture. Assuming all the cells are identical, major discharge will destroy the 3-packs on either end of the stackup. They will discharge faster than the 6-packs and reverse-bias when about 50% of the stack capacity has been reached. Bad, bad, bad idea.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast so including diode is a must right? sigh, 0.7 Volt down again :(

also I found out power bank QC 3.0, I think max they give 12 volt ( maybe there is some better build and brand that I haven notice )

Comment: @TerryLim - You don't seem to understand your battery packs. You clearly have sets of 3 or 6 in parallel, and unless all sets have the same number in parallel you're going to kill cells. Also, you can get Schottky diodes with about half the voltage drop. But until you understand some basics you're going to get in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your batteries provide a maximum of 216 watts, and likely significantly less in the Real World.
- Simply connecting batteries in parallel is a tricky thing to do without damage or catastrophe.  One method of providing a safe method involves using series diodes and/or resistors to "balance" the current and prevent the batteries from charging/discharging each other. Either series diodes or series resistors will further significantly reduce the power from your batter packs.
- A DC-DC converter will further severely limit the amount of power you have available. You probably won't find any DC-DC converters in any serious electric vehicle design because they are just not efficient enough. Match the battery voltage to the motor by selecting the right battery and/or the right motor.
- Grounding is the least of your concerns. Conventionally, you would select the common side of the circuit (typically the negative bus) and call that "ground" and connect it to the chassis.  But it doesn't have any great significance connected or floating.

The three main show stoppers in your design are:

1. Your proposed batteries don't provide even HALF the amount of power that your motor wants.  You need a much better match between battery and motor.
2. Simply connecting batteries in parallel is risky and dangerous. NOT RECOMMENDED without taking proper precautions.
3. Using DC-DC converter is not efficient enough for anything but a small toy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, much appreciated,

what If i combined 3 group of converter so that BCM will have close to 600W as input?

but then again, I need 36 power banks, which is quite crazy :(

by the way,by including diode will eliminate the "dangerous" parallel risk?

Comment: Using isolation diodes on each battery eliminates the dangerous parallel risk, but it doesn't balance the current. So it won't solve the load-balancing problem. The "power budget" in most electric vehicles is so narrow that using diodes or resistors is rarely done because it wastes so much power.  Matching the battery and the motor is a MUCH MUCH preferable method. Even using your battery packs in SERIES would be a much better idea. It wouldn't be the first time a 240V DC motor was used in a vehicle.